# `ndimage.distance_transform_bf` transforms the wrong elements?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

From the documentation of `ndimage.distance_transform_bf`:

> This function calculates the distance transform of the `input`, by
>   replacing each background element (zero values), with its shortest
>   distance to the foreground (any element non-zero).

Now let's try it in code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
square = np.zeros((16, 16))
square[4:-4, 4:-4] = 1
plt.imshow(square)
```

[image]

```
dist = ndimage.distance_transform_bf(square)
plt.imshow(dist)
```

[image]

Clearly, the function is transforming foreground elements instead of background. Is this an obvious bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The function has [unit tests](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/bcbb9381bc5cf7868b2f96c59302ef04faafa6d9/scipy/ndimage/tests/test_ndimage.py#L2520) where this behavior is checked, so it appears to be a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: I created a scipy issue for this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7360